# Determineing if operators with a pseudo inverse are projection operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:
Let $\mathcal A$ be an $\mathcal m \times n$ matrix with rank $\mathcal n$ and let $\mathcal A^\dagger$ be its pseudo-inverse. Determine if the operator, $\mathcal AA^\dagger$, is a projection operator. If so what subspace do they project onto?

Correct me where I'm wrong (possibly everywhere):
This operator, $\mathcal AA^\dagger$, returns the identity matrix, which should be in the same subspace as $\mathcal A$, right? What would this be?

Comment: What is your definition of a projection operator?

Comment: @amd I'm not 100% sure. We've only been talking about orthogonal projection operators, does that make sense?

Comment: Most generally, a projection $P$ satisfies $P\circ P=P$. Orthogonal projections have some other properties besides, but that’s the important one to verify.

Comment: @amd Gotcha. So assuming that it returns an identity matrix, then I^2=I, so it is an orthogonal projection? Would this be in R^n as well?

Comment: Be careful. The pseudo-inverse is not In general a right inverse, i.e., $\mathcal A\mathcal A^\dagger\ne I$. This product is, however, the identity on a certain subspace of $\mathbb R^m$ (and that’s a clue to the solution of this problem).