# Matrix times its pseudo-inverse equals the identity matrix. How do we determine the rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So I have a matrix, $\mathcal A$, and its pseudo inverse, $\mathcal A^\dagger$. If $\mathcal A$ is $\mathcal m \times n$ with rank $\mathcal n$, what would be the rank of this new identity matrix formed by the operator $\mathcal AA^\dagger$? This identity matrix would have to be square, right? Does this mean it's in subspace $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: what does "this new identity matrix formed by the operator $\mathcal A \mathcal A^\dagger$" mean?

Comment: I thought that a matrix times its inverse equals the identity matrix, right?

Comment: Non-square matrices don't have an inverse. It is called *pseudo* inverse for reason.

Comment: Well shoot. Then what is the significance of $\mathcal A A^\dagger$?

Comment: it depends on which pseudo inverse you consider.

Comment: If you’re talking about the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse here, then $\mathcal A\mathcal A^\dagger$ and $\mathcal A$ have the same image. This is one of the results of [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2134089/265466).

Answer (score 2):

If $m \ge n$ then the rank of $A$ is less than or equal to $n$. If $m<n$ then the rank of $A$ is less than or equal to $m$. Thus, I assume that 
$m\geq n$.
Let $A=USV^t$ be the SVD (singular value decomposition) of the matrix $A$ where $U$ is an $m\times n$ orthogonal matrix (that is $U^tU$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix) $V$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix and $S$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries ordered in the non-increasing order. These entries have to be positive; otherwise the rank of $A$ would be less than $n$.

The Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $A$ is given by $A^{+} = V  S^{-1} U^t$. Thus,  $AA^{+} = USV^t V S^{-1} U^t = U U^t$ which is an $m \times m$. This is an identity matrix if and only if $m=n$ in which case, you can replace the pseudo inverse by the standard inverse. The rank of $AA^{+}$ is given by the rank of $U$, which is $n$.

Note that $AA^{+}A = A$. If $A$ is a non-singular square matrix then $AA^{-1}A = A$. Thus, the pseudo inverse behaves like a normal inverse in this case.